f2py in numpy 2.0.1 does not expose variables the way numpy 1.26 did. How can I access Fortran variables in Python?
I used to run a collection of Fortran 95 subroutines from Python by compiling it via f2py. In the Fortran source I have a module with my global variables:
   MODULE GEOPLOT_GLOBALS
     IMPLICIT NONE
     INTEGER, PARAMETER :: N_MAX = 16
     INTEGER, PARAMETER :: I_MAX = 18
     INTEGER, PARAMETER :: J_MAX = 72
     ...
   END MODULE GEOPLOT_GLOBALS

The compiled file has the name "geoplot.cpython-312-darwin.so" and is in a subfolder named "geo". When using f2py in numpy 1.26, I could do this:
import geo.geoplot as geo
maxN = geo.geoplot_globals.n_max
maxI = geo.geoplot_globals.i_max
maxJ = geo.geoplot_globals.j_max

Now, with numpy 2.0.1, I do the same but get the error message
AttributeError: module 'geo.geoplot' has no attribute 'geoplot_globals'

Which can be confirmed by listing the __dict__ attribute or using the getmembers module: They all list the Fortran subroutines and modules which contain source code, except for the geoplot_globals module which contains only variable declarations.
So my question is: How am I supposed to access global Fortran variables from Python when using numpy 2.0? And please do not suggest to write all to a file in Fortran only to read it in Python. There should be a more direct way.

This must be a bug in f2py. See here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/27167
What got me unstuck is an ugly workaround: I simply added some useless dummy code to the module, like that:
MODULE GEOPLOT_GLOBALS
    USE MOD_TYPES
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: N_MAX = 16
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: I_MAX = 18
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: J_MAX = 72
    ...
    CONTAINS
    SUBROUTINE DUMMY (UNSINN)
        INTEGER :: UNSINN
        OPEN(UNIT=29, FILE="FOR29.txt", STATUS = 'UNKNOWN')
        WRITE(29,"(I8)") UNSINN
        CLOSE (29)
    END SUBROUTINE DUMMY
END MODULE GEOPLOT_GLOBALS

Now the before missing module is carried over into Python and can be accessed in the usual way.
>>> print(geo.geoplot_globals.__doc__)
n_max : 'i'-scalar
i_max : 'i'-scalar
j_max : 'i'-scalar
...


What helped me fix a similar problem is to use the f2py module to create a wrapper for the Fortran code. Add the BIND(C) attribute to your module and variables like this:
MODULE GEOPLOT_GLOBALS
  USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER, PARAMETER, BIND(C) :: N_MAX = 16
  INTEGER, PARAMETER, BIND(C) :: I_MAX = 18
  INTEGER, PARAMETER, BIND(C) :: J_MAX = 72
END MODULE GEOPLOT_GLOBALS

Recompile your code using 'f2py'. And then using ctypes, you can do this in your Python code:
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.CDLL("geoplot.cpython-312-darwin.so")

n_max = ctypes.c_int.in_dll(lib, "n_max").value
i_max = ctypes.c_int.in_dll(lib, "i_max").value
j_max = ctypes.c_int.in_dll(lib, "j_max").value

Hope it helps.

This might work in Windows, but as you can tell from the "darwin" part, I am not compiling a dll, but a shared library for MacOS. I still get the AttributeError when I follow your advice.
